# Kafka (0.9.0.1) Offsets Jump Backwards After Application Restart

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

During an application run, offsets are manually committed in sequence. Here is a segment of our log file, with the highlight representing the offset:

---

2016-12-21 17:01:22.887|0.0|SYNC|1|2016-12-18 21:39:54.154|64632980|1|**3284934**|...

2016-12-21 17:01:22.888|0.0|SYNC|1|2016-12-18 21:39:54.169|64683699|1|**3284935**|...

2016-12-21 17:01:22.888|0.0|SYNC|1|2016-12-18 21:39:54.185|64705181|1|**3284936**|...

2016-12-21 17:01:22.913|0|PROG-TERM|1||   <--Stop application

2016-12-21 17:01:46.171|0|PROG-START|1||  <--Restart

2016-12-21 17:01:47.536|4316.5|SYNC|1|2016-12-14 03:01:49.581|1900001405|2|**3126234**|...

2016-12-21 17:01:51.863|0.3|SYNC|1|2016-12-14 03:09:10.457|1900001410|1|**3121208**|...

2016-12-21 17:01:51.864|0.1|SYNC|1|2016-12-14 03:09:10.839|1900001410|1|**3121209**|...

---

As you can see, the offset jumps from 3284936 *back* to 3126234. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is this the same partition? Maybe it reads different partition.

Comment: What is the Kafka client version?

Comment: @pconrey you ever figure this out?